# Pine-Script + Multiple Symbol Strategy

Tags: pine-script

I would like to know if it is possible in TradingView to backtest multiple Symbol in the same script ? 
In other words, stand out from the symbol applied to the graphic.

I found how to call other symbol with the commande security, but after to place order, i don't succeed to stand out the symbol applied to the graph.

Thank you !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strategy orders are only generated on the chart's symbol. You can use `security()` to fetch information from other tickers to use in your calcs, but orders cannot be executed on them.

Comment: Why not adding the features? First off; the max number of charts is 8 so it means we cannot go beyond 8 symbols trading. Not sure what is the holdup!

Comment: The request for the feature is already logged, but it is not in the pipeline yet, so there's no ETA.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use only one symbol in the chart. you can use security function to fetch data from another symbolss up to 40 symbols.